# HTML to PDF conversion from hosted ASP classic?

Tags: asp-classic, pdf-generation

I need to convert HTML to PDF on the fly from a hosted ASP classic page.

WkHtmlToPDF is great, but unfortunately requires installation on the server which is not possible in this case.

Is there something out there that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a third party component to do this.

I've found that classic ASP hosts often install the "Persits" suite of tools, including [AspPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/manual_13.html).  If your hosting doesn't have it (it's pretty common), and they won't install something for you, you may want to consider new hosting, or maybe [some sort of web service](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/features#simpleapi) to perform this task (which will probably cost you).